# How to have multiple instances of one jQuery player object in a page (Audio object)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, javascript-objects

I have made a customised audio player, but the problem is that I can only have one player in each HTML page. Because so since the js code is associated to for example class `.play`then if there are 2 `.play` classes on the page, both work.  While the only one that is pressed is supposed to work. Here is a very simplified version of the player. I know this example can be solved by using `this` in some part of the code, but imagine it is a full plugin with lots of functionalities.

```js
(function($) {
  var audio, src;
  src = $(".player").attr("data-src");
  audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = src;

  $(".play").on("click", function() {
    if (audio.paused) {
      audio.play();
      $(".play").css("background", "url(https://goo.gl/w4q23U) no-repeat");
    } else {
      audio.pause();
      $(".play").css("background", "url(https://goo.gl/xOkUZm) no-repeat");
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
div.player{
  width:200px;
  height:50px;
  border:dashed 1px black;
  margin:5px;
}
div.player > .play {
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  background: url(https://goo.gl/xOkUZm) no-repeat;
  float:left;
}
div.player > .title{
  line-height:50px;
  margin-left:60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="player" data-src="https://goo.gl/aBJE48">
  <div class="play"></div>
  <div class="title">track 1</div>
</div>

<div class="player" data-src="https://goo.gl/4arvDT">
  <div class="play"></div>
  <div class="title">track 2</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, if you press button to play, both icons works, while only the one that is pressed is supposed to work. I am looking for a proper solution for having various instances of the same plugin in a single page.

There are similar question with this title, but the point of this question is considering the audio object which the page can only play one of them, no matter if there is one instance of the player of multiple.

Answer (score 1):

Pass a "target" for your CSS and also push each instance into an array so you can call methods on them using index position. Then the controls will apply to the instance you have selected.

```
(function($) {
  var player = [];
  var audio, src;
  src = $(".player").attr("data-src");
  audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = src;
  player.push(audio);
  $(".play").on("click", function(target) {
     $.each( player, function( key, value ) {
      if (audio[key].paused() {
      audio[key].play();
      $(target).css("background", "url(https://goo.gl/w4q23U) no-repeat");
    } else {
      audio[key].pause();
      $(target).css("background", "url(https://goo.gl/xOkUZm) no-repeat");
    }

  });

  });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, I am not sure what you mean by passing `target` for the CSS. Can you please show me how to do it?

Comment: "target" is just the reference you are passing that represents the current object you clicked on. I have already updated your script to include a target and the requisite array, as well as the loop you will need.

Comment: I couldnt get it running anyways, seems like there is an error with `audio[key].paused`

Comment: Yeah, my mistake - I forgot the opening parenthesis on the paused function call. I have fixed it in the code above. Should not throw an error again.